# Run some common code before and after a block

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a current project, I found myself often writing code like so:

```
statement_x()

do_something()
do_other_thing()

statement_y()

# ...

statement_x()

do_third_thing()
do_fourth_thing()

statement_y()
```

As you can see, `statement_x` and `statement_y` often get repeated, and they are always paired, but I am unable to condense them into a single statement. What I would really like is a language construct like this:

```
def env wrapping:
    statement_x()

    run_code

    statement_y()
```

In this case, I'm pretending `env` is a Python keyword indicating a special "sandwich function" that runs certain statements before and after a given block, the point of entry of the block being indicated by the second keyword `run_code`.

My above program can now be made more readable using this construct:

```
env wrapping:
    do_something()
    do_other_thing()

env wrapping:
    do_third_thing()
    do_fourth_thing()
```

Which I mean to have the exact same behavior.

---

As far as I know such a construct does not exist, and the point of my question is not to speculate on future Python features. However, surely this situation of "run some common code before and after a variable block" must occur often enough that Python has a convenient way of dealing with it! What is this way? Or is the Pythonic solution to simple give up and accept the repetition?

***PS:*** I realize that I could write a function that takes the variable statements as an argument, but that would not be very user-friendly - I would end up writing huge lists of statements inside the parens of my function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Example using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
import contextlib                                                               

@contextlib.contextmanager
def doing_xy():
    print('statement_x')
    yield
    print('statement_y')
```

Example usage:

```
>>> with doing_xy():
...     print('do_something')
...     print('do_other_thing')
... 
statement_x
do_something
do_other_thing
statement_y
>>> with doing_xy():
...     print('do_third_thing')
...     print('do_fourth_thing')
... 
statement_x
do_third_thing
do_fourth_thing
statement_y
```

Comment: A further benefit of the `with` statement is that the `statement_y` bit that runs after the block of code gets run even if the block raised an exception.

Comment: @Blckknght, To do that, `yield` statement and the rest should be guarded with `try .. finally ...`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I should have said: "it allows you to have `statement_y` run even if an exception is raised". You do have to do a little bit of work to enable it.